# Why $BA +AB = A+B$?

Tags: matrices

Given $BA = A$ and $AB = B$  and $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices, why does $BA +AB = A+B$ ?

Please explain.

ADDED:

The actual problem is it was given that,$BA = A$ and $AB = B$ hence find the value of $A^2 + B^2$.

I simply utilized the fact that if $BA = A$ and $AB = B$ then $A$ and $B$ are idempotent matrices, hence $A^2 + B^2 = A + B$ but the module solution is something more algebraic they break $A^2 + B^2$ and then performs usual substitution after that they showed the result but I don't understand how $BA +AB = A+B$.

Comment: This isn't true.  Have you misquoted a problem?

Comment: Erm. Isnt this just a trivial matter of substituting in the given conditions?

Comment: As you edited, $BA=A$ and $AB=B$, is a given of the problem, not something to be derived.  But $BA=A$ doesn't make either one idempotent.

Comment: @Ross: $A^2=A(BA)=(AB)A=BA=A$.

Comment: @George:  OK thanks

Comment: After the edit the question has become trivial.

Comment: @ George Lowther: Oh damn,stupid me.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't true in general. For example take $A$ as the zero matrix and $B$ as the identity matrix. Then the left hand side is just the zero matrix and the right hand side is the identity matrix, which are not the same.

Comment: Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true, indeed consider the case when $A = 0 $ is the zero matrix and $B= Id$ is the identity, then LHS is the zero matrix but RHS is the identity.